# Not able to serialize MemoryStream in .NET Core 3

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

I have used MemoryStream to serialize the data but In .NET Core 3 project throws below exception.

Please suggest a solution to resolve this.

System.IO.MemoryStream mystream=  ((System.IO.MemoryStream)(resources.GetObject("LayoutStream")));

Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' in System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll
Type 'System.IO.MemoryStream' in Assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' is not marked as serializable.

Comment: It is already in embedded resource only. it works fine in Net Core2.0. But it fails only in 3.0

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/5460

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/17460

Comment: Could not find any solution from above link? and already gone through this link. Please suggest any other solution.

Comment: I'm getting the same with net50: `"Type 'System.RuntimeType' in Assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' is not marked as serializable."`  
Has there been a solution to this issue?